# How to get address of connected USB modem?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, devices, modem

I just connected my N81 telephone as USB modem to Linux Mint 14. All works fine, just wondering how to find a full path to this device, something like `/dev/tty*`.

Comment: take a look at `lsusb -v` but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Kiwy yeah, there it is: 'Bus 003 Device 013: ID 0421:0007 Nokia Mobile Phones' But no address provided

Comment: maybe `ls -l /dev/` could allow you to identify the thing if you find the number of nod maybe 3,13 in your case but I can't assure it

Answer (score 6):

Probably too late, but it might help others. Wouldn't help you to use [`mmcli`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/ModemManager/man/latest/mmcli.8.html) from [ModemManager](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ModemManager/)?

```
$ mmcli -L

Found 1 modems:
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/4 [Lenovo] H5321 gw

$ mmcli -m 4 

/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/4 (device id '34391e5ed3c2b2b7f11d7b36
53147e93414a8c06')
  -------------------------
  Hardware |   manufacturer: 'Lenovo'
           |          model: 'H5321 gw'
           |       revision: 'R3C11'
           |      supported: 'gsm-umts'
           |        current: 'gsm-umts'
           |   equipment id: '358993042510275'
  -------------------------
  System   |         device: '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4'
           |        drivers: 'cdc_acm, cdc_wdm, cdc_ncm'
           |         plugin: 'Ericsson MBM'
           |   primary port: 'cdc-wdm2'
           |          ports: 'cdc-wdm2 (at), wwp0s20u4i6 (net), cdc-wdm1 (at), 
ttyACM1 (at), ttyACM2 (gps), ttyACM0 (at)'
  ...
```

Comment: The kernel folks say to remove ModemManager because it causes too many problems. I'm not sure I agree. I think the problem is in the device or the way the device is setup. Also see [How to make /dev/ttyACM0 (and friends) exclusive?](https://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2019-March/019828.html)

Comment: Well, in https://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2019-March/019834.html Greg KH just says, that if person handles modem with own peace of code, than it cannot use ModemManager as they're fighting over serial line with each other. That's not a general statement that ModemManager is bad and should be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Solution 1: Run `dmesg` and watch out for `ttyUSB*` lines if your modem interface is a classical emulated serial interface.

Solution 2: Browse `/sys/bus/usb/devices/X-1:Y:*/` until you find useful information.

Based on your line `Bus 003 Device 013: ID 0421:0007 Nokia Mobile Phones`, i would guess X=3 and Y= 12 (13 minus one).

Solution 3: Run `udevadm monitor` as you plug your USB device.

Comment: How do you translate *`Bus 003 Device 013: ID 0421:0007 Nokia Mobile Phones`* to a device like `/dev/ttyACM4`?